# Unable to install Plex on Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: software-installation

I am running v20.4 and I am unable to install Plex media server onto it from the downloads file or from the terminal.

It looks like it's going to install and then just stops and offers me the remove option. The terminal looks like it has installed but I don't find Plex on the PC.

Comment: You haven't said how or where you downloaded it, and I don't see it in Ubuntu repositories so providing details of where, how you installed, any messages during installation & on attempted execution may help us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the easiest way to install Plex Media Server on Ubuntu 18.04 and newer (I just happened to do this last week):

1. DON'T download anything manually.
2. Run the command `sudo snap install plexmediaserver`. That snap is maintained, tested, and regularly updated by the Plex developers
3. Snaps are deliberately sandboxed, so Plex cannot access most of your system. Your movies/music/books must be located in either:

   - A subdirectory of /home/your_username, or
   - A subdirectory of /media

   Example of creating a subdirectory and mounting a movie-filled partition to that subdirectory:

   ```
    sudo mkdir /media/movies
    sudo mount /dev/sdx2 /media/movies
   ```
4. Open a web browser to:

   - http://localhost:32400 (your local machine), or
   - http://<ip_address>:32400 (different machine on your LAN)


     After the first local login, subsequent logins to Plex can use the web service at http://plex.tv
5. Use the Plex Web Interface to locate and scan the media libraries that you mounted in Step #3.

Comment: Once installed via snap, what are the instructions for starting/stopping the service?  I've found 'sudo service plexmediaseerver start/stop/status' but I get the message that plexmediaserver.service is not found.

Comment: @Dennis play with `snap start` and `snap stop` (See `man snap`). When you figure it out, please offer an edit to this answer.

Comment: @user535753 Thanks for your reply.  I found that there is a PPA installation for plexmediaserver, and I'm going with that. I really like the idea of standardized software implemenations (avoiding docker, snap, homebroew, composer and on and on - each with its own learning curve).  Simpler is better.